# can I reach mongodb collections without creating model? (mongoose)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to finish a project to get a part-time job and I got stuck in here.

**The problem is:** There are 2 JSON files given for products and categories. I uploaded these JSON files using MongoDB Compass. How can I reach these 2 documents and their collections in my code? Because I need to use them to create a website. Is there a way to do this, or:

Do I have to create Schema and Model, and after that read objects from JSON files in my code, create instances and save them one by one to my database?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please provide sample code that you already tried and is related to this question. Try not to ask multiple questions that are not related to main problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use the **db** property of your mongoose instance and issue queries directly as needed - if you need to bypass your Models for some reason.

Models and defined schema are what many find to be the benefit of using Mongoose. You don't have to use Mongoose and can use the [official Nodejs](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/) driver too.

To access db directly in Mongoose:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect(`mongodb://localhost/mydb`, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, autoIndex: false});
const db = mongoose.connection;

db.db.collection('mycollection').find({});
```